# Allauth redirect to 'account/login/None' when i login/signup

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

When I create an account or log in with an existing one, Allauth redirects to 'account/login/None' or 'account/signup/None', but I am logged in and create the account successfully

views:

```
class LoginView(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin,
                AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin,
                FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "account/login.html"
    success_url = "/"
    redirect_field_name = "next"
    # ....

class SignupView(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, CloseableSignupMixin,
                 AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "account/signup.html"
    form_class = SignupForm
    redirect_field_name = "next"
    success_url = "/"
    # ....
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('account/', include('allauth.urls'), name='account'),
    # ....
]
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{redirect_field_value}}">
```

Check whether you had given this in your custom login html if so remove it.

For Example
You have page which requires login example (localhost/dashboard) So when you access this url it will redirect to (localhost/login/?next=/dashboard/) where 'next'({{ redirect_field_name }}) value is 'dashboard' . So after you login it goes to dashboard page.
But if you go to (localhost/login/) where next value will be 'None' so it will go to 'localhost/login/None' no matter if you had given LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings page it will always go to the page based on the hidden input value that is 'redirect_field_name'.

Note: If you remove the above hidden input after every login the page redirect to the url mentioned in LOGIN_DIRECT_URL

Comment: I think, it's better to configure that `{{ redirect_field_value }}` to be able to redirect to pages requiring authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure `redirect_field_value` in your **LoginView**, or use *if* statement in your template in case the value is undefined:

```
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
```